# Function not running, something is wrong in my CSS somewhere but where?

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, toggle

I'm working on a project and using a code along to help me understand how to build an Nav Bar. I am using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXkqy0b4M5g
I've haven't gone past 22:05 in the video.

I've built out the HTML, CSS and first JavaScript function which is supposed to show the navbar when you click on the hamburger menu which we've built out of div's. I've built out the function in JavaScript, I am receiving no errors, and everything matches the video to a "T" and looks 100% right but for whatever reason it will not run the function when I click the hamburger menu.

```js
console.log("Hello!");

const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");

  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
  });
}

navSlide();
```

```css
nav .nav-links {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  height: 92vh;
  top: 8vh;
  background-color: #366576;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 30%;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

nav .nav-links li {
  opacity: 0;
}

.burger {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}


}
.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <h4>Logo</h4>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li>
      <a href="#header">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I've been at this for over 24 hours now and I cannot for the life of me find anything wrong. Everything is linked and again, I am not seeing any errors. It works exactly like this on the video I was following along with. Anyone have any clue what's going on here?

Comment: Event listener runs fine here, as long as you give the clickable element some content

Comment: `.burger`'s height is 0 so you're not really clicking on anything.

Comment: @dork I've got the `.burger` class set at `width: 25px` and `height: 2px` so it has some content on the screen. I am able to click on it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've got the `.burger` class set at `width: 25px` and `height: 2px`.

Comment: Oh okay, it's not in your snippet. But if you can click on it, then the `nav-active` class gets toggled. So it's not a JS issue but a CSS one.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the media query and the screen sizes.

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");

  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation){
        link.style.animation = '';
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 1.5}s`;
      }
    });

    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
  });
}

navSlide();
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: #504954;
    font-family: 'Popins', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
    color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 30%;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
    color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.burger {
    display: none;
}

.burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-links {
        width: 60%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: #504954;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }

    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .burger {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

.toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px)
}

.toggle .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,6px)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
          <h4>Logo</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
          <li>
            <a href="#header">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="burger">
          <div class="line1"></div>
          <div class="line2"></div>
          <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped solve my issue. I was using `nav .nav-links` as a selector in my CSS and using simply `.nav-links` in my JS file. I _think_ thats what my issue was. Either way I am back on track. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the classes `line1`, `line2`, and `line3` are not defined and the "hamburger" occupies no screen space for you to click. I made `.burger` visible by:

```
<div class="burger">
  <div class="line1">---</div>
  <div class="line2">...</div>
  <div class="line3">---</div>
</div>
```

and added some logging:

```
burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(nav.classList[1]);
  nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
  console.log(nav.classList[1]);
});
```

If you click the "hamburger" repeatedly, the console should show alternating `undefined` and `nav-active` each time.

Comment: I've got the `.burger` class set at `width: 25px` and `height: 2px` so it has some content on the screen and does show up and there is content.  I added your console logs and they do what you've said they should do but it is still not doing what it should be. The `.nav-active { transform: translateX(0%);}` is still not being called.

Comment: In that case it's not a Javascript problem and the title of your post is incorrect. Looks more like a css issue then.